# can not see the real exception in gradle tests

Tags: java, testing, gradle, logging

I have test class A that extends some base class **from external library**

```
class A extends com.thirdparty.BaseClass {

    @Test public void test () {
        System.out.println("executing test")
    }
}
```

meanwhile BaseClass always throws exception in its constructor

```
class BaseClass {
    BaseClass() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception")
    }
}
```

in that case when I run test with **gradle** from command line, it gives me **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** error, and I have no clue that the real exception is RuntimeException.

What I want, is to see the real **RuntimeException** anywhere.

I've tried

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        showStandartStreams = true
    }
}
```

but it gave no result.

Gradle version is 4.1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test something, do it inside a test method. You don't declare your test class like this.

```
class A extends com.thirdparty.BaseClass {
```

When the exception is thrown, the testing framework won't recognize it as a test result, but as a failure that occured while setting up, which is why it throws its own exception to reflect this. If you want to test that your constructor throws an exception, do it like this.

```
class A {
    @Test(expected = RuntimeException::class)
    public void testConstructorThrowsException() {
        BaseClass()
    }
}
```

Comment: In BaseClass there are complex methods to setup environment. I support that 3rd party library. And it throws exception if configuration is not valid. Exception is not what I want to test. I see that gradle replace exception with its own, but it becomes much harder to investigave that issue, because I cant see the real exception